# Details list in symfony2, from two bundles

Tags: symfony, listview

I have little in the development of Symfony and I have a question: To show a list with details of two Bundles.

My project have a Owner, but can have 1 o more consultants. The Entity has been related but when the results are listed only can view  the user id. How can see the user name?

I will attach a image with my entities.

Thanks,
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcuCD.png)
[Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGxYd.png)

Comment: Show the twig code please, maybe you are not looping over the relationship correctly...

Comment: and the php code of your entities

Answer (score 0):

I need show the name of the differents consultants in a project. These are users too. I have already related the owner of the project, but this consultant is a field in my entity.

Attachment images to reference, and the php and twig files content. See the image: [Database relation, and view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw38R.png)

```
UserProjectController

public function showAction(UserProject $userProject, User $user) {
    $id      = $userProject->getId();
    $em      = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $project = $em->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Project')->find($id);
    $userProjects = $em->getRepository('ProjectBundle:UserProject')->findby(array('idproject' => $id, 'status' => '1'));
    if (empty($userProjects)) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('userproject_new');
    }
    $users = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findby(array('id' => 1));

    return $this->render('ProjectBundle:Userproject:show.html.twig', array(
            'userProjects' => $userProjects, 'project' => $project, 'User' => $user,
        ));
}
```

Entity User

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectBundle\Entity\UserProject", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $uproject;
```

Entity UserProject

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="userproject")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $idproject;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="uproject")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $user;
```

Entity Project

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectBundle\Entity\UserProject", mappedBy="idproject")
 */
protected $userproject;
```

View show.html.twig

```
{% for userProject in userProjects %}
    <br>
    <dl>
    <dt><span class="text-primary">{{'User_id'|trans}}</span></dt>
        <dd>
            {{ userProject.user }}
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <br>
        <dt><span class="text-primary">{{'Consultor_id'|trans}}</span></dt>
        <dd>
            {{ userProject.consultorId }}
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <br>
        <dt><span class="text-primary">{{'Status'|trans}}</span></dt>
        <dd>
            {% if userProject.status == 1 %}
                <span class="text-success">{% trans %}Enabled{% endtrans %}</span>
            {% elseif userProject.status == 0 %}
                <span class="text-danger">{% trans %}Disabled{% endtrans %}</span>
            {% endif %}
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <br>
    </dl>
{% endfor %}
```